# Please add summary list for flags against a user, like on other flag views

Tags: feature-request, flags, profile-page, moderator-tools

The user page includes link to a summary of flags raised and what happened to them, like this:

[image: user-raised flags]

The links in the summary make it easier to find or review particular flags or groups -- very helpful!

Similarly, the flags dashboard used by moderators has a summary of active flags:

[image: active flags]

There's one other place where flags congregate.  As with the dashboard, it's only visible to moderators.  Unlike the mod dashboard (on my sites), it often has more than a few entries.  I'm talking about the list of flags raised against a user.  Could we have a summary there too?  There's room and it'd really help for certain types of issues.  I mean something like this:

[image: mockup showing categories like for flags raised]

I grouped flagged comments together at the bottom because we have a page for that already, so you could just link to it.  If the flags were helpful those comments aren't going to be on this page anyway.  (Also, these numbers are made-up, in case anyone's wondering.)

Right now we see a total number of flags on user pages, but not all flags reflect poorly on the user.  Some are declined, some are auto-flags caused by other users' behavior,<sup>1</sup> some are self-flags (e.g. "I edited; could this be undeleted now?"), and some are neutral.  I'd like to be better able to understand the whole picture.

We *do* have a list of the most *recent* flags, nicely presented.  That's a big help!  I'm asking for this table of contents *too*, because sometimes we need to review more of the history.  I hope that you've already done most of the work of design and implementation for other reasons and this addition would not require a huge effort.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, two *other* users arguing in comments can cause a "too many comments" flag.  Another user leaving the Nth recent rude comment triggers a "too many rude comments" on the last post (because we can't flag users).  There are some others.

Comment: I love this idea. Right now flags on users' posts and comments are split into separate pages with no filter options. Why not also display this list in the user's mod dashboard?